# Carregar o googlemaps em JQuery

Tags: google-maps

Estou tentando carregar um mapa, só que o mapa não inicializa.

O código que uso para carregar o mapa:

```
function carregaMapa(endereco) {
var address = endereco;
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(16);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,

            position: results[0].geometry.location

        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro ?

Comment: Já consegui resolver, tinha esquecido de iniciar o mapa. Obrigada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para carregar o mapa, primeiro você precisa inicializar o mapa, tente usar o código abaixo:

```
function iniciaMapa() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

}

e depois

```
$(document).ready(function () {
iniciaMapa();
```

});

Comment: Obrigada! Deu certo!